# How to transform: translate element through whole screen on Android?

Tags: android, ios, reactjs, react-native, css-transforms

I'm working on some animations in React Native and I noticed that on Android, the `transform: [{ translateY: height }]` doesn't take the whole screen like on iOS. On Android it just takes it's own height. How can I make the Android animation look like the iOS one?

Android:
[image: Android]

iOS:
[image: iOS]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try adding the animated style to the top view of list items, and match the list's width and height to the screen

Answer (score 1):

The problem was the Touchable wrapping the image:

```
<TouchableHighlight key={item.id} onPress={handlePress}>
  <Animated.View
    onLayout={handleOnLayout}
    style={[this.animatedImageStyle(item.id)]}
  >
    <Image
      onLayout={handleOnLayout}
      ref={node => (this.nodes[item.id] = node)}
      source={{ uri: item.uri }}
      style={[styles.image]}
    />
  </Animated.View>
</TouchableHighlight>
```

Moving the `Animated.View` outside Touchable Wrapper solved the issue:

```
  <View key={item.id}>
    <Animated.View
      onLayout={handleOnLayout}
      style={[this.animatedImageStyle(item.id)]}
    >
      <Image
        onLayout={handleOnLayout}
        ref={node => (this.nodes[item.id] = node)}
        source={{ uri: item.uri }}
        style={[styles.image]}
      />
    </Animated.View>
    <TouchableWithoutFeedback onPress={handlePress}>
      <View style={[styles.image, { opacity: 0, marginTop: -75 }]} />
    </TouchableWithoutFeedback>
  </View>
```